# Simple but slow query on million records table in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

Hello friends and thanks for your help in advance.

I am performing a simple query that performs a join between two tables:

```
SELECT
F5_CNOMBRE,
F5_CTD,
F5_CNUMSER,
F5_CNUMDOC,
F5_DFECDOC,
F5_NIMPORT,
CD_DFECCAN,
CD_CCODART
FROM ft1
INNER JOIN cc1
ON RTRIM(cc1.CD_CNRODOC) = RTRIM(ft1.F5_CNUMSER) + ft1.F5_CNUMDOC
WHERE F5_CGLOSA LIKE @varNroExpediente + '%'
```

The table ft1 has around 1 millions of records and the table cc1 has around 700 000.

The query runs fast when no one is writing on/using those tables, but when users are using them the query takes around 30/50 seconds to finish.

I was thinking on creating an indexed view, indexing the fields ft1.F5_CNUMSER and ft1.F5_CNUMDOC. I think this would improve the performance. I wanted your opinion on the subject also, if I create the index(s) on the view is there any chance the queried tables could be damaged on the operation, those are very important tables for the actual system.

I appreciate the insight I can get on the subject.

Comment: Is there a good reason that `CD_CNRODOC` and `F5_CNUMSER` aren't trimmed in the database?  Is there an index on `ft1` with both `F5_CNUMSER` (trimmed) and `F5_CNUMDOC` in it?  (That is one index with two columns.)  Are the index statistics current?

Comment: @HABO Unfortunately those trims are necessary because some of the data is in with blanks included. The table has no active indexes therefore no active index stats in my understanding.

Comment: Are those 8 columns you select only a fraction of the columns of those two tables? Or do they make up almost the whole tables?

Comment: @marc_s ft1 table has 90 columns and cc1 has 57 columns

Answer (score 4):

Seeing that your two tables have a total of 147 columns, but you're "only" selecting 8 of them (a good thing!), you might get a good performance boost by having two indices on your tables:

- on table `ft1`, create an index on `F5_CGLOSA` (which you use in the `WHERE` clause) and include the other columns from that table:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX IX01_ft1 
  ON dbo.ft1 (F5_CGLOSA)
  INCLUDE(F5_CNOMBRE, F5_CTD, F5_CNUMSER, F5_CNUMDOC, F5_DFECDOC, F5_NIMPORT)
  ```
- on the other table, `cc1`, create an index on the smaller of the two columns (depending on their datatype) and include the other column - I just "guessed" it could be something like this:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX IX01_ft1 
  ON dbo.cc1(CD_DFECCAN)
  INCLUDE(CD_CCODART)
  ```

That way, your query (all its columns it needs) are "covered" by those two indices, and being able to just scan those two indices (and combine the results from those scans) instead of having to scan the full tables (which are much bigger, much more columns) could bring a significant improvement (hopefully!).

Comment: Thanks, instead of creating the indexes on the table can I create them on the view?. I don't have table modification privileges. BTW, the field Glosa is not a unique field (is a comments field).

Comment: @CoderRoller: no, you cannot create an index on a view - unless you've made it an *indexed* view (created a clustered index on that view). Also: `F5_CGLOSA` doesn't need to be unique - it's just being indexed, that's all

Answer (score 2):

Certainly materializing that join with an indexed view might be useful because the join is so nasty. Indexes cannot help much with it. When creating the view, make F5_CGLOSA the first clustered index column so your query can seek on it.

Not sure if this is possible for you but can you a) change the join columns so you don't have to join on function results and become SARGable and b) find out why concurrent users of that query cause blocking? Maybe you can solve this problem by just turning on snapshot isolation.

Comment: Thank you, I think there is no way to change the join but I was thinking on adding the isolation too, I will try and see how this behaves on production. If I add an indexed view for the query, the indexes set on it could harm the tables?

Comment: You can't do any harm, except that writes are slightly slower and some schema operations are no longer possible (for example, rename a column that is also in the view).